# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class when using exec();

Tags: php, linux, centos, exec

I'm writing a web app, and I created a scraper to get data from my own site.

I have a few dependencies, so they're being extended, but now that I'm trying to run this php script from exec, and it doesn't work, I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Helpers\ScraperHelper' not found in /home/username/public_html/App/Libraries/Scraper/execute.php:6.

**Begin.php**

This is how I'm calling my script:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php/ home/username/public_htm/App/Libraries/Scraper/execute.php');
```

**Execute.php**

```
namespace App\Libraries\Scraper;

use \App\Helpers\ScraperHelper;

$recipe = new ScraperHelper();
$recipe->fromFeed();
```

`fromFeed()` runs the script that's included in the `ScraperHelper class`, scrape the information from the site and inserts it into the database.

I've tried removing all the namespaces, and using require with full server path, but there are a 4 other dependencies that doesn't allow me to access them.

```
require_once '/home/username/public_html/App/Helpers/ScraperHelper.php';
require_once '/home/username/public_html/App/Models/Food.php';
require_once '/home/username/public_html/Core/Model.php';
```

Composer is autoloading two folders. Core and App, but I figure that the `exec` function ignores it which is why I keep getting `Uncaught Error.`

I believe `exec` isn't being able to process the namespaces and use calls, I included all the files with `require_once` and it worked, but It's not what I need still, I really need to know how to make exec process namespaces, use calls.

Comment: not sure if its the issue, but PHP can run a separate  php.ini config for the Command Line ( CLI ).  So you can wind up with environmental issues.   Also if you rely on `$_SERVER` super Global that can be vastly different when not running under Apache.

Comment: Other then that, make sure your autoloader is being included in the call stack.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Just to clear things up, I spent over 5 hours last night trying to get this working.. I created a file, and included the autoloader and called the function from there, all is working. I am having problems with move_uploaded_file not working, I believe I'll have to check $_SERVER like you mentioned above. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Sure, for SEVER some things like the Host name, and Address, will not be accessible when not running on the apache server.  Which makes perfect sense, but is easy to overlook.